# Failed prop type: The prop todos[0].id is marked as required in TodoList, but its value is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to do the [redux basic usage tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) which uses react for the UI.

I'm getting this warning (in red though - perhaps it is an error?) in the console logs when I click a button labelled "Add Todo":

> warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos[0].id` is
>   marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
>       in TodoList (created by Connect(TodoList))
>       in Connect(TodoList) (at App.js:9)
>       in div (at App.js:7)
>       in App (at index.js:12)
>       in Provider (at index.js:11)

So the todo that is getting added, has no id field - I need to figure out how to add an id.

in `actions.js`

```
/*
 * action creators
 */

export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}
```

actions/index.js

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}

export const setVisibilityFilter = (filter) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
    filter
  }
}

export const toggleTodo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
    id
  }
}
```

containers/AddTodo.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

It looks like `actions/index.js` does add the todo `id`?

It's hard to debug because for some reason the chrome dev tools sources are missing the actions and reducers folders of my app:

[image]

[image]

How do I get the todos[0] to have a unique id?

note that when I add `id: 1` here it does get the id added but it is not unique:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false,
          id: 1
        }
      ]
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Maybe:

```
/*
 * action creators
 */

export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}
```

needs `id` added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I briefly looked over your code, and I believe you're not getting that `id` because you're not importing the action creator function you think you are.

in **containers/AddTodo.js**:

```
import { addTodo } from '../actions'
```

In your project, you have

```
./src/actions.js
./src/actions/index.js
```

When you import or require anything (without using file extensions like the above `'../actions'`), the JS interpreter will look to see if there's a file called **actions.js** in the **src** folder. If there is none, it will then see if there's an **actions** folder with an **index.js** file within it.

Since you have both, your AddTodo component is importing using the action creator in **./src/actions.js**, which does not have an `id` property as you had originally guessed.

Remove that file, and it should work as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an 'id' variable to the actions file then increase the value every time you call the action creator.

action creator:

```
let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
});
```

reducer:

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id, // unique id
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```