# Unable to run redux todo example (todos array undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Although there is a very similar question at:
[Failed prop type: The prop todos[0].id is marked as required in TodoList, but its value is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785077/failed-prop-type-the-prop-todos0-id-is-marked-as-required-in-todolist-but-it)

Looks like only the symptoms are the same (I corrected all the imports as advised)

I can add a todo element, but when I click on an element, somehow the `todos` array becomes `undefined`, and the following error is printed out to the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos[0]` is marked as required in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

I have created a minimal example repository, which manifests the problem at:
https://github.com/klaszlo/redux-todo-nonworking

(( original example: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos ))

Step to reproduce:

I. Install dependencies:

```
git clone https://github.com/klaszlo/redux-todo-nonworking.git
cd redux-todo-nonworking 
npm install
```

II. Build:

```
npm run build
```

III. Run local server:

```
cd dist && npm run test:server
```

IV. Navigate in browser to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

V. BUG to reproduce

1. add a todo element
2. click on it (and watch the javascript output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your git repo. I found that you have not returned the created todo object in todos.js reducer for action `TOGGLE_TODO`.

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
console.log('todo state:', state);
  return state.map(todo => {
    console.log('inside state', todo);
    return (todo.id === action.id) ? Object.assign({}, todo, {completed: !todo.completed}) : todo
  })
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `todos` reducer listening to `TOGGLE_TODO`. In order to do the `console.log` you have changed the `()` in the arrow function to `{}`, but forgot to use the `return` necessary for the `Array.prototype.map` function.
Use this:

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
console.log('todo state:', state);
  return state.map(todo => (
    (todo.id === action.id) ? Object.assign({}, todo, {completed: !todo.completed}) : todo
  )
```